# Zoom canvas drawing on button click?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm currently working on a project to update the visual representation of a certain genome database. I have most of the functionality completed and am stuck on this problem (as I am very new to webdev). What I want to do is allow users to click on the canvas element and then expand/enlarge said element.

I have tried a few tutorials on adding zoom functionality/enlarging via CSS but haven't had any luck since most are based off of static images (.png, .jpgs etc files)

Specifically, I have been trying to implement this tutorial (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-scaling-a-drawing-with-plus-and-minus-buttons/)

My base code is as such:

```
 if (isset($_POST['gene']))
            {
                $geneIndex = file("geneIndex.txt");
                $refGene = file("refGene.txt"); //load relevent files

                $results = findLineNumbers($search_term, $geneIndex);

                $CANVAS_WIDTH = 1280;
                $CANVAS_HEIGHT = 0;
                $CAMVAS_HEIGHT_ITERATOR = 60;
                $y_pos = 30;
                $canvas_x = "canvas";

                for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($results); $i++){
                    $CANVAS_HEIGHT += $CAMVAS_HEIGHT_ITERATOR;//changes canvas height based on num of exons
                }

                print "<canvas id=\"$canvas_x\" width=$CANVAS_WIDTH height=$CANVAS_HEIGHT style=\"border:1px solid #c3c3c3;\">";
                print "Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.";
                print "</canvas>";
                print "<script>";

                ?>

                var c = document.getElementById("<?php echo $canvas_x; ?>");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = "#273c61"; // colour


                <?php for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($results); $x++) {
                    $tempnc = str_replace(array('.', ','), '', $results[$x]); //remove commas from array

                    if ($tempnc != null) {

                        $data = $refGene[$tempnc - 1]; //for some reason the line is offset by one, have to take away one for proper line to be found

                        $datacsv = explode("\t", $data, 16);
                        $direction = $datacsv[3];
                        $start_first_exon = $datacsv[4];
                        $end_last_exon = $datacsv[5];
                        $num_of_exons = $datacsv[8];
                        $coding_region_start = $datacsv[6];
                        $coding_region_end = $datacsv[7];
                        $start_positions = explode(',', $datacsv[9]);
                        $end_positions = explode(',', $datacsv[10]);

                        draw($num_of_exons, $start_positions, $end_positions, $start_first_exon, $end_last_exon, $target_positions, $coding_region_start, $coding_region_end, $canvas_x, $y_pos, $CANVAS_HEIGHT, $direction); //draws the diagram item
                        $y_pos += $CAMVAS_HEIGHT_ITERATOR; //changes pos of next item on diagram for next iteration

                        }
                    }


               print "</script>";
?>
```

So basically in the code above I am grabbing "coordinates" from two files and then using them to draw the diagram. This works fine, I just need to integrate the tutorial linked above into my solution.

I have already tried integrating it but have been having many problems.

This is my current version of the implementation:

```
 if (isset($_POST['gene']))
            {
                $geneIndex = file("geneIndex.txt");
                $refGene = file("refGene.txt"); //load relevent files

                $results = findLineNumbers($search_term, $geneIndex);

                $CANVAS_WIDTH = 1280;
                $CANVAS_HEIGHT = 0;
                $CAMVAS_HEIGHT_ITERATOR = 60;
                $y_pos = 30;
                $canvas_x = "myCanvas";

                for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($results); $i++){
                    $CANVAS_HEIGHT += $CAMVAS_HEIGHT_ITERATOR;//changes canvas height based on num of exons
                }    

                    print "<canvas id=\"$canvas_x\" width=\"$CANVAS_WIDTH\" height=\"$CANVAS_HEIGHT\" style=\"border:1px solid #c3c3c3;\"></canvas>";

                    print "<input type=\"button\" id=\"plus\" value=\"+\">";
                    print "<input type=\"button\" id=\"minus\" value=\"-\">";


                    print "<script>";
                ?>



                var c = document.getElementById("<?php echo $canvas_x; ?>");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = "#273c61"; // colour

            function draw(scale, translatePos){

                <?php for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($results); $x++) {
                    $tempnc = str_replace(array('.', ','), '', $results[$x]); //remove commas from array

                    if ($tempnc != null) {

                        $data = $refGene[$tempnc - 1]; //for some reason the line is offset by one, have to take away one for proper line to be found

                        $datacsv = explode("\t", $data, 16);
                        $direction = $datacsv[3];
                        $start_first_exon = $datacsv[4];
                        $end_last_exon = $datacsv[5];
                        $num_of_exons = $datacsv[8];
                        $coding_region_start = $datacsv[6];
                        $coding_region_end = $datacsv[7];
                        $start_positions = explode(',', $datacsv[9]);
                        $end_positions = explode(',', $datacsv[10]);

                        ?>



                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
                        ctx.save();
                        ctx.translate(translatePos.x, translatePos.y);
                        ctx.scale(scale, scale);

                       <?php draw($num_of_exons, $start_positions, $end_positions, $start_first_exon, $end_last_exon, $target_positions, $coding_region_start, $coding_region_end, $canvas_x, $y_pos, $CANVAS_HEIGHT, $direction);
                        $y_pos += $CAMVAS_HEIGHT_ITERATOR;


                        }
                    }

                ?>

            }

            window.onload = function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById('<?php echo $canvas_x; ?>');

                var translatePos = {
                x: canvas.width / 2,
                y: canvas.height / 2
                };

            var scale = 1.0;
            var scaleMultiplier = 0.8;
            var startDragOffset = {};
            var mouseDown = false;

            // add button event listeners
            document.getElementById('plus').addEventListener('click', function() {
            scale /= scaleMultiplier;
            draw(scale, translatePos);
            }, false);

            document.getElementById('minus').addEventListener('click', function() {
            scale *= scaleMultiplier;
            draw(scale, translatePos);
            }, false);

            // add event listeners to handle screen drag
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
            mouseDown = true;
            startDragOffset.x = evt.clientX - translatePos.x;
            startDragOffset.y = evt.clientY - translatePos.y;
            });

            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt) {
            mouseDown = false;
            });

            canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', function(evt) {
            mouseDown = false;
            });

            canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', function(evt) {
            mouseDown = false;
            });

            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
            if(mouseDown) {
            translatePos.x = evt.clientX - startDragOffset.x;
            translatePos.y = evt.clientY - startDragOffset.y;
            draw(scale, translatePos);
            }
            });
            draw(scale, translatePos);
            };

                </script>

       <?php
          //...some other code here

}
```

With the above code nothing appears in my diagram.

Any tips for integrating the tutorial code with my base code? I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that work-->

1. Draw your image on canvas.
2. Using setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) and clearRect make this canvas clear for zoomed drawing.
3. Now save this context.
4. Scale to the desired extent(ctx.scale).
5. Draw on the canvas using ctx.drawImage
6. Restore context (ctx.restore)

Besides,if you want to zoom from the center you can translate the context to the center and then bring it back to the original position.Cheere:)
Include steps 2-6 in a function and trigger it on the action you want to perform zooming(button click)

Answer (score -1):

For visualizing data and especially zooming in and out canvas is not optimal at best, because it is raster graphics.

You should seriously consider using vector graphics SVG and/or d3 http://d3js.org/